Looking for a choose your own adventure book with a talking skull necklace
I remember my dad giving me this choose your own adventure book as a kid and I can't remember what it was. All I remember is there was a skull necklace that would talk to the protagonist, and that in one of the bad endings the protagonist tries to attack a slime that melts his sword and kills him.

Return to Firetop Mountain had a talking necklace. I think it made you hallucinate voices.

I believe I've found it. It's Return to Brookmere (1982) by Rose Estes, from the Dungeons & Dragons: Endless Quest series. The necklace is not a skull but a dragon.

The reader, as Brion the elf, must drive out a horde of monsters from his father's castle and locate a treasure hidden in the dungeon.


I owned a copy of this book... fond memories.
